# Wrap ef core database update in a transaction

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

My recent database update failed in the middle of a migration, leaving the database inconsistent:

```
> dotnet ef database update 
Applying migration '20200429031727_NewRequisitesAndCountry'.
Failed executing DbCommand (97ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[...]
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not 
permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there a way to wrap the migration in a transaction? I am interested in doing so both from the command line and programmatically while calling `context.Database.Migrate()`.

Comment: Someone tried wrapping context.Database.Migrate() in a transaction and got an exception: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12325